# how to get the data bound to an instance of a user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Hello to all the pros....

My name is elli and im doing some project for school, i will very much appreciate you advice.

I have a number of instances of a user control in my aspx page. the data in the user control i get from a datalist.

inside the control i have a button. what im trying to do is like that:

when a user clicks the button, i want to find out what row from the datalist is presented in this specific control, and store it in, lets say, session.

my problem right now is when i click the button, nothing happens, i tried just to put a simple Response.Redirect in the onButton_click in the code behind...

im working on it already 2 days and im kinda lost.

This is the partial code of the user control, the relevant thing, i guess, is the image button...right on the top

this is the user control ascx

```
                    <div id="video play button icon" style="height: 27px; width: 121px;
                    float: left"><asp:ImageButton ID="PlayButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Search_Results_Images/search_Play_Button_Icon.png" onclick="PlayButton_Click" />
                </div>
                <div style="height: 27px; width: 22px; float: left">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="height: 15px; width: 434px; background-color: transparent; float: left">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
<div style="width:84px"></div>
</SeparatorTemplate>
```

this is the code behing the user control

```
public partial class SearchBullet : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String tmpcmd;
    tmpcmd = (String)(Session["mainSearchQRY"]);
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = tmpcmd;


}
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");
}

}
```

thank you very much,
elli pertzov

Answer (score 0):

Your click event isn't wired up correctly, in the markup you've said `onclick="PlayButton_Click"`, but in your code-behind your method is called `btnClick_Click`